# How to customize a toolbar in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, customization

I am trying to customize Eclipse to speed up development and minimize distractions for Android Java development.

I am using SourceGear Vault for source control and installed the plugin for Eclipse.  So to check stuff in/out, I have to right click on the Project/File, go to Team submenu, then pick a source control command (Check In, Check Out, Get Latest, etc...).  I find this process slow. I'd like a button on the toolbar and a keyboard shortcut to do these operations.

I tried going to `Customize Perspective`, but under Team toolbar, there is only `Synchronize` command.
And I have no idea how to setup a shortcut for the SCC operations either as they are not present in Shortcuts tab.

Am I missing something simple?

Comment: This might not be what you are looking, but I had the same issue in Eclipse. Then I tried IntelliJ IDEA for Android development and I found out everything was where I wanted right from the start.

Comment: @TomislavMarkovski Wow, I can't believe I suffered this long.

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/116974/how-can-you-remove-icons-from-the-eclipse-myeclipse-main-toolbar

Comment: Official Doc: https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9n.htm

Answer (score 39, accepted):

(Revised)

Look in the Command Groups Availability tab of the dialog you get when you do the `Customize Perspective` and you should see an entry related to your VCS; turn this entry on and then go back to the Toolbar Visibility and you should see more stuff (under the name of the VCS). The `Team` area is *not* going to have what you want; the commands are grouped by the VCS name, like git, SVN, etc.

Sorry for the initial answer, I mis-read part of your question.

Comment: Please reconsider this, I changed the answer after more carefully reading your question.

Comment: Typically your answer would be correct, but the SourceGear Vault plugin is very spartan at best and its group is not under Command Groups Availability.  Thus I can't make it available under Toolbar Visibility.  Anyway, since no answer exists, I'll accept yours.

Comment: Francis, you are polite/diplomatic guy! Thank you for that!

Answer (score 15):

**Eclipse Photon**

- Window
- Perspective
- Customize Perspective

Now you can check and uncheck checkboxes to customize the buttons that show up.

Tested on Photon Release Candidate 3 (4.8.0RC3).

Comment: Works like that also/still in Eclipse 2019-09.

Comment: Works like that also/still in Eclipse 2021-06 :)

Answer (score 4):

I find that if you are currently using a base perspective that comes standard with the Eclipse install you need to: "Window -> Save Perspective As..." first. Then you can just customise the tool bar as you please.

Comment: Correct, modifying a "built-in" perspective like _Debug_ etc. won't work. Didn't know that. Eclipse is better than Notepad but usually Notepad causes less problems and makes people less angry.